# Выравнивание заголовка по ширине с отступом без переносов

Tags: вёрстка, latex

Необходимо выровнять заголовок по стандарту, вот образец:

[image: как должно быть]

Я воспользовался пакетом `titlesec`, однако не смог добиться нужного результата:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
%========================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа
\usepackage{titlesec} %пакет для оформления заголовков

% Установка параметров для документа
%========================================================
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\frenchspacing  %после знаков препинания пробелы не увеличиваются (по умолчанию эти пробелы увеличиваются в соответствии с англо-саксонской традицией)
\parindent=1.25cm %красная строка

%параметры заголовков разделов (глав)
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{0bp}{\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}

%\hyphenpenalty=10000 % - подставить в 1 параметр, чтоб отменить переносы

%параметры заголовков подразделов (секций)
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

%параметры заголовков пунктов (подсекций)
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize}{\thesubsection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Очень-очень длинный заголовок, в котором нужно сделать разрыв}

    Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины, — ты один мне поддержка и опора, о великий, могучий, правдивый и свободный русский язык! Не будь тебя — как не впасть в отчаяние при виде всего, что совершается дома? Но нельзя верить, чтобы такой язык не был дан великому народу!
    
    \section{Характеристика ООО «Вектор»}
    
    Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины, — ты один мне поддержка и опора, о великий, могучий, правдивый и свободный русский язык! Не будь тебя — как не впасть в отчаяние при виде всего, что совершается дома? Но нельзя верить, чтобы такой язык не был дан великому народу!     
\end{document}
```

С этим кодом получается наиболее близкий результат, но без отступов:

[image: как получилось]

Пробовал подставлять `\hspace{\parindent}` перед `\thechapter`, но это ничего не дало - вся граница заголовка сдвигается влево, а не только отступ.

Пробовал менять опцию `hang`, но там нет ничего подходящего. `runin` немного подходит в плане отступа, но заголовок слетает чёрт знает, куда:

[image: использование runin]

Если есть какой-то другой способ сделать этот заголовок (без данного пакета) - то готов принять и это решение.

Дистрибутив: TeXLive

Компилятор: XeLaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю какого эффекта Вы хотите добиться, то достаточно использовать стиль оформления **block** вместо **hang** - это должно перевести заголовок в режим вёрстки обычного абзаца. А там уже нормально работает команда для вставки пробела заданного размера.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
%========================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа
\usepackage{titlesec} %пакет для оформления заголовков

% Установка параметров для документа
%========================================================
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\frenchspacing  %после знаков препинания пробелы не увеличиваются (по умолчанию эти пробелы увеличиваются в соответствии с англо-саксонской традицией)
\parindent=1.25cm %красная строка

%параметры заголовков разделов (глав)
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\hspace{\parindent}\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{0bp}{\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}

%\hyphenpenalty=10000 % - подставить в 1 параметр, чтоб отменить переносы

%параметры заголовков подразделов (секций)
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

%параметры заголовков пунктов (подсекций)
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize}{\thesubsection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Очень-очень длинный заголовок, который должен использовать до трех строк при текущих настройках стиля, в котором нужно сделать разрыв}

    Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины, — ты один мне поддержка и опора, о великий, могучий, правдивый и свободный русский язык! Не будь тебя — как не впасть в отчаяние при виде всего, что совершается дома? Но нельзя верить, чтобы такой язык не был дан великому народу!
    
    \section{Характеристика ООО «Вектор»}
    
    Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины, — ты один мне поддержка и опора, о великий, могучий, правдивый и свободный русский язык! Не будь тебя — как не впасть в отчаяние при виде всего, что совершается дома? Но нельзя верить, чтобы такой язык не был дан великому народу!     
\end{document}
```

Результат получился такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сработало! Благодарю! Разве что от себя добавил ещё туда команду ```\sloppy``` - даёт тот самый эффект, что в примере (растяжение пробелов).